# Moving dynamically loaded content in the DOM using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, blogs

I'm using a blog template - squarespace 6, which doesn't allow me access to the .html / and only limited access to the .css

Each time I create a blog post I add tags and a category to it - but these tags/category are placed at the bottom of the blog post. I'm trying to move them to the sidebar.

The problem is that I have multiple blog posts per page, I'm trying to use jquery to select the `.tags` and `.category` classes and move them into the `.sidebar`before the `.date` with code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $categories = $('div.categories').parent('article');
var $spanDate =('span.date').parent('article');  

$categories.insertBefore($spanDate);

});
```

*(this code is only the example for .categories)*

The problem is this code grabs the tags/category from every blog post and applies it to every sidebar so categories and tags are getting mixed up.

I'm trying to get the code to select the `.tags` and `.category` of a parent article and then move those to the .`sidebar` of the same parent `article`.

I can't use any specific ID's because I want this to apply to every blog post - but the tags/category need to stay within that post.

There is a lot of injected code but the basic structure of the HTML is as follows:

```
<blog>  //Wrapper for the whole blog page
<content>
<article> //Each article is a blog entry
  <section class="main"> //Contains the contents of the blog entry. This also has a dynamically generated ID, 
    //Blog Entry Content Goes Here
    <footer>
      <div class="meta"> //Contains the tags/categories I try to pull out of the DOM
        <span class="tags"></span> //Contains the tags each wrapped in an `<a>`
        <span class="categories"></span> //Contains the category tags
      </div>
    </footer>
   </section>
   <section class="sidebar"> //This is where I'm trying to place the tags/categories
     <span class="date"></span> //I try to place the category before this in the jquery code above
     <more spans....> // I try to place the tags appended onto the end of the sidebar (code not shown above).
   </section>
</article>
<article></article> //More blog entries with same structure
<article></article> //More blog entries with same structure
<article></article> //More blog entries with same structure
</content>
</blog>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample of the html.

Comment: @James added html structure - should have put that in from the start

Comment: did you try to for each the articles and using the articles as context in the jquery call? like (dummy code) $('articles').each(function(articelElem){$('div.categories', articelElem) .... })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, this should do:

```
$('div.categories').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $date = $this.closest("article").find(".date");

    $this.insertBefore($date);
});
```

The key is that for each `.categories` I find the related `.date` rather than all `.date`s.  Also, your code shouldn't do anything at all with the supplied html.  Neither your `.categories` or your `.date` has a direct parent of `article`.